# Inexplicably cleared msbuild properties in TeamCity build

Tags: msbuild, nuget, teamcity

I'm trying to create a "tools NuGet package" that provides a tool and setting that is unpacked during build and used by a later TeamCity build step.

The NuGet package contains the following content in its `build\MyPackageId.props` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <MyTool1>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\tools\MyTool.exe</MyTool1>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Target Name="ReportMyToolToTeamCity" BeforeTargets="PrepareToRun">
        <PropertyGroup>
            <MyTool2>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\tools\MyTool.exe</MyTool2>
        </PropertyGroup>
        <Message Text="MyTool1 = $(MyTool1)" />
        <Message Text="MyTool2 = $(MyTool2)" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

(The messages will eventually set a TeamCity property, but this is sufficient to demonstrate the issue.)

Because it's a props file, after installing the NuGet package into a C# project it has added an import as the very first thing, above the import of `Microsoft.Common.props`.  I want a props file rather than a targets file so that the property values are also available to other project settings and targets files.

When I compile this inside Visual Studio 2015, I see both `MyTool1` and `MyTool2` paths set to the same (correct) path as expected.

When I compile this from TeamCity (2017.2.2, using the Visual Studio (sln) runner), according to the output the `MyTool1` property is empty and only `MyTool2` shows the correct value.

Why?